# Cannot save my uploaded image to local disk folder

Tags: laravel, crud

I am currently building a CRUD application using Laravel. It requires me to upload images and information but seems like there are some problems on storing the images to the `localdisk` folder.

Here is my controller code:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $lostitem =new Admin();


        $this->validate($request, [
            'date' => 'required',
            'TimeFound' => 'required',
            'AreaWhereFound' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'Remark' => 'required',
            'DateClaimed' => 'required',
            'TimeClaimed' => 'required',
            'CategoryID'=>'required'
        ]);


        $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();



        // $record = new Admin;
        // return view('students.create');
        $lostitem->code = $uuid;
        $lostitem->date = $request->date;

        $lostitem->TimeFound = $request->TimeFound;
        $lostitem->AreaWhereFound = $request->AreaWhereFound;
        $lostitem->image = $request->image;


         if($request->hasfile('image'))
       {
            $filenameWithExt=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension =$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore=$filename.'_'  .time().'.'.$extension;
            $path=$request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);


                // $file = $request->file('image');
                //  $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();//getting image extensionimage
                //  $filename=time()  ."." .$extension;

                //   $file->move('uploads',$filename->getClientOriginal);

                //   //getting from data base


            }
         else
         {
            //  $lostitem->image = "";
            $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';

         }
        $lostitem->image = $request->image ;
        $lostitem->Remark = $request->Remark;
        $lostitem->DateClaimed = $request->inputDateClaimed;
        $lostitem->TimeClaimed = $request->TimeClaimed;
        $lostitem->CategoryID = $request->CategoryID;

        $lostitem->save();
         return redirect(route('LostItem_add'))->with('successMsg', 'Record added!');
    }
```

The other information is saved. I hope to get help.

Comment: Whats is the error? Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in view? ...
Controller method is in first look ok.

Comment: yes there is enctype="multipart/form-data" in the view

Comment: So is thesr some error? Or the script just runs without saving the image?

Comment: everything is saved, instead the image .i would like to save it on local disk folder, for me to retrieve it

Comment: First check if the image is really on the disk or not, than if you are stepping in condition `$request->hasfile('image')` and then I dont think you wanted do this: `$lostitem->image = $request->image;`, correct should be `$lostitem->image = $fileNameToStore;`

Comment: sorry, I think I did not declare the problem clearly. I would like to upload an image (from C disk) and from  the code, I have written, I like to save it on public/images

and the issue is, the image does not  save on the public/images folder

Answer (score 0):

Change Your controller code to this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $lostitem =new Admin();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'date' => 'required',
        'TimeFound' => 'required',
        'AreaWhereFound' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'Remark' => 'required',
        'DateClaimed' => 'required',
        'TimeClaimed' => 'required',
        'CategoryID'=>'required'
    ]);

    $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();

    $lostitem->code = $uuid;
    $lostitem->date = $request->date;
    $lostitem->TimeFound = $request->TimeFound;
    $lostitem->AreaWhereFound = $request->AreaWhereFound;
    $lostitem->image = $request->image;

    if($request->hasfile('image')){
        $filenameWithExt=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension =$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore=$filename.'_'  .time().'.'.$extension;
        $path=$request->file('image')->move(public_path('images/'),$fileNameToStore);
    }
    else{
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }

    $lostitem->image = $request->image ;
    $lostitem->Remark = $request->Remark;
    $lostitem->DateClaimed = $request->inputDateClaimed;
    $lostitem->TimeClaimed = $request->TimeClaimed;
    $lostitem->CategoryID = $request->CategoryID;
    $lostitem->save();
    return redirect(route('LostItem_add'))->with('successMsg', 'Record added!');
}
```

And then access your image in the blade like this

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->image) }}">
```

And make sure that you do have an folder named "images" in the public directory

Answer (score 0):

Save the path of image in database

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $lostitem =new Admin();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'date' => 'required',
        'TimeFound' => 'required',
        'AreaWhereFound' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'Remark' => 'required',
        'DateClaimed' => 'required',
        'TimeClaimed' => 'required',
        'CategoryID'=>'required'
    ]);

    $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();

    $lostitem->code = $uuid;
    $lostitem->date = $request->date;
    $lostitem->TimeFound = $request->TimeFound;
    $lostitem->AreaWhereFound = $request->AreaWhereFound;
    $lostitem->image = $request->image;

    if($request->hasfile('image')){
        $filenameWithExt=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension =$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore=$filename.'_'  .time().'.'.$extension;
        $path=$request->file('image')->move(public_path('images/'),$fileNameToStore);
    }
    else{
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }

    $lostitem->image = $path ;
    $lostitem->Remark = $request->Remark;
    $lostitem->DateClaimed = $request->inputDateClaimed;
    $lostitem->TimeClaimed = $request->TimeClaimed;
    $lostitem->CategoryID = $request->CategoryID;
    $lostitem->save();
    return redirect(route('LostItem_add'))->with('successMsg', 'Record added!');
}
```

& show it

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->image) }}">
```

Comment: hello, I have try this code already, but it still doesn't work. is there another error?

Comment: can you give the value which is save in your database??means what image value & name you save in your database?

Comment: In the database on xammp its save as 
[BLOB-24B]

Comment: and i was using an binary datatype in laravel  For the image