# Laravel. image cannot be display

Tags: laravel, image, crud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfBzF.png)Photo is in public/image folder

and the image cannot be fetched properly

```
@foreach($lostitem as $item)
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{ $item->LostItemID }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $item->date }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $item->TimeFound }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $item->AreaWhereFound }}</td>
                     <td><img src="{{ asset('public/images/'.$item->image) }}" alr="image"></td>
                     <td>{{ $item->Remark }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $item->UserLevelID }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $item->DateClaimed }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $item->TimeClaimed }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $item->created_at->format('Y-m-d g:i a') }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $item->updated_at }}</td>
                     <td>
                     <a  href="{{route('LostItem_edit', $item->code) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                     </a>
                     <form method="POST"
                         action="{{ route('LostItem_delete', $item->code) }}">
                         {{ csrf_field() }}
                         {{ method_field('delete') }}
                         <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure?');">
                             <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                         </button>
                     </form>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             @endforeach
```

this is the  code is used in the view to fetch the photo

Answer (score 0):

You have already used `asset()` so you dont have to write public inside path
Try with this . Hope this helps

```
<td><img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->image) }}" alr="image"></td>
```

Although it cant be the definite solution because it really depends upon how you have saved your image and its better if u have posted the controller logic too .
Let me know !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232006/cannot-save-my-upload-image-to-local-disk-folder?noredirect=1#comment108324185_61232006  Here is my controller code

Comment: @JUSTINCHUA check my answer then it may help !

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't work, does my code have another problem?

Comment: Can me share me what is $item->image giving just dd that and send me that

Comment: Also while saving the image I can see in my controller there is a problem . 
you are saving $request->image rather than $path

Comment: sorry I don't get what you were saying..   $item->image is for the name of the item
even if remove it the image still not display properly

Comment: @JUSTINCHUA you are not saving the image properly so it is not showing I guess

Comment: could you figure out where is the error on my code on a store procedure, I been troubleshoot for two days but it still doesn't work. thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Change your this code from this

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/images/'.$item->image) }}
```

to this :

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/'.$item->image) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried your suggestion but it's not working.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232006/cannot-save-my-upload-image-to-local-disk-folder?noredirect=1#comment108324185_61232006  Here is my controller code

Comment: @JUSTINCHUA Okay. I've posted an answer on your above question. Go and kindly check there and I hope it'll help you

Comment: @Khlid Khan i have try the code you provide buut its was still not working ....

Answer (score 0):

Here You just Ignore the public because you use asset..In the simplest form, assets means JavaScript, CSS, and images which lie directly under the public directory and are publicly accessible using a URL.

Laravel provides a helper function, asset(), which generates a URL for your assets.

So just add write this

```
<td><img src="{{ asset('/images/'.$item->image) }}" alr="image"></td>
```

But My suggestion to you that when you save the file on database you save it with the all path after public path

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried your suggestion but it's not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232006/cannot-save-my-upload-image-to-local-disk-folder?noredirect=1#comment108324185_61232006   here it is

Comment: here you change two thinks..you save the file into database with just original image name..but when you store it on your images folder you save it with a time() function....the two images are not same then...

Comment: i gave you an answer on that

Answer (score 0):

how about use `url()`

```
<img src="{{url('images/'.$item->image)}}" alt="Image"/>
```

Comment: maybe the problem is your permission try
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public/image/image.jpg` and `sudo chmod -R 755 public/image/image.jpg`